# What MySQL data type to use for long decimal?

Tags: mysql

I have to store positive, decimal numbers like the following:
0.00005438543978579432

What is the best MySQL data type to store this type of information?

I wanted to use DECIMAL(1, 20), but the first argument has to be >= to the second argument. In my case, the positive ones digit will always be 0, so there will never be a case where I would  need to store 20 digits before the ".", so it seems like a waste to have a column with data type DECIMAL(20,20).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECIMAL(20,20)
```

This says a total of 20 digits, with 20 of those digits after the decimal point. (Which means there are at most 0 digits before the decimal point.)

The precision (the first value) includes ALL of the digits, both before and after the decimal point, the total number of digits.

That's why `DECIMAL(M,N)` specifies `M >= N.` To allow for a single digit before the decimal point, then you would need `M = N+1`, e.g. DECIMAL(21,20).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html